# A pram, a stroller, or a baby carriage?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What would most Americans call this: A pram, a stroller, or a baby carriage? Or something else?

[image]

Comment: @JamesK That question is about British English and this question is about American English, which use different words for this.

Comment: If you read the answers, they cover both dialects

Answer (score 1):

They might call it any of those, but *stroller* is the US term. If you were to call this a stroller in the UK it would be very unusual.

Your intended area may have its own preference, other names include:

- buggy
- pram
- push chair

Baby carriage would be understood but very old fashioned.

*Which one to use?*

Choose Stroller in the USA, and either pram or push chair elsewhere. Regionally people may disagree but you will discover this quickly and people will generally understand.

Comment: The pictured item is certainly not a buggy, nor a push chair (as it is for newborns to lie flat, not for older babies to sit in)

Comment: I've seen items such as the one pictured that tilt so that the child can sit up, and I've seen numerous english speaking people in England name them that way even when they are strictly for newborns to lie flat. Without knowing the precise model number pictured you cannot be sure ( and plenty of people would **still** call it such ). Case in point if you search for baby carriage you get plenty of models that cannot lay flat with baby carriage in their product name

Answer (score 0):

The picture shows two items that can be purchased independently, or combined as a "travel system". British English uses several names interchangeably for the base / carrycot / whole system and the same may be true for US English.

The US online retailer Amazon lists similar items advertised as "strollers" and "bassinets". "Travel systems" are also mentioned.

[image]

US consumers *may* (and this is my speculation) use some terms interchangeably and sometimes inaccurately as we frequently do in England. For example, British people would happily call this a pushchair (even though it's not a chair) unless accuracy was paramount. e.g. "Darling, we need to buy a replacement *carrycot* for the stroller / pushchair."

Answer (score -1):

Most Americans prefer to call it "a stroller", because "a pram" is a British English and "baby carriage" is an English understand

I doesn't matter what most Americans call it, but the fact the meaning are the same

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "is an English understand".